# How can I create an array from a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Let's say my data frame horizontal looks like:

```
['name','age','gender']
```

Is there a way to use the column name such that I only have an array of the names like:

```
['Charles','Beatrix','James', 'ect']
```

Comment: `df['name']`? This is really basic, I suggest you reread a pandas tutorial before trying anything else.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: From the docs ___10(!) minutes___ _to pandas_: [Getting started / 10 min / Selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
df[column_name].to_list() # df is dataframe
```